# Bigcommerce api no response

Tags: php, api, oauth, bigcommerce

I have some trouble getting a response from the new Bigcommerce api, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Followed the instructions to get an Oauth token upon app install here:

```
developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/callback
```

The token is stored and used to make this request:

```
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store hash}/v2/time
```

According to `developer.bigcommerce.com/api/authentication`:

I've added `X-Auth-Client` and `X-Auth-Token` respectively as the app client ID and Oauth token.

The server is just returning `"0 NO RESPONSE"` and I'm not sure what's wrong. It does return unauthorized if I remove one of the headers though.

Does anyone have an idea on this? Thank you.

--
I'm using the Advanced Rest Client app from chrome to test for responses. Basically calling my store's URL api.bigcommerce.com/stores/3t984h/v2/time as a GET request and passing `X-Auth-Client` and `X-Auth-Token` headers.

```
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
X-Auth-Client: p1r37bt131z86675nofv9xmhietoe4t
X-Auth-Token: kzm1q2w8h11dfkgbxhg3j0i8amac86g
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,ko;q=0.4,en-GB;q=0.2,en-US;q=0.2
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can help.

Comment: Anyone has any idea ? I was thinking I might be lacking an additional header value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. It was a spec issue which wasn't that obvious (to me at least).
According to this (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/headers)

I needed to add

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

to the request header for it go thru.